# How to pass multiple arguments from Jolie to an embedded Java service?

Tags: java

I want to pass more than one parameter to an embedded Java Service from Jolie.
Here is my code for the Jolie program and Java program:

**Jolie program:**

```
include "console.iol"

type NandRequest:void {
.number[2,*]: bool
}

interface NANDInterface {
    RequestResponse: test(NandRequest)(bool)
}

outputPort NAND {
    Interfaces: NANDInterface
}

embedded {
    Java: "example.NAND" in NAND
}

main
{

     request.number[0] = true;
     request.number[1] = true;
     test@NAND(request)(response);
     println@Console( response )()
}
```

**Java program:**
package example;

```
import jolie.runtime.JavaService;

public class NAND extends JavaService{

    public java.lang.Boolean test(final java.lang.Boolean x , final java.lang.Boolean y) {

        java.lang.Boolean r = !(x&&y);
        return r;

    }
}
```

But when I run the Jolie service , it gives error as 'jolie.runtime.InvalidException: invalid identifier:test

What is the correct way to pass such multiple parameters?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is to use the class `Value` from package `jolie.runtime` in `jolie.jar`, which allows you to navigate the data tree passed from Jolie as a map:

```
package example;

import jolie.runtime.JavaService;
import jolie.runtime.Value;
import jolie.runtime.ValueVector;

public class NAND extends JavaService
{
     public Boolean test( Value request )
     {
         ValueVector vec = request.getChildren( "number" );
         for( Value v : vec ) {
             if ( !v.boolValue() ) return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
}
```

I took the liberty to adapt your code to a generic array.

If you'd like to have automatic conversion from a Jolie value to a Java object of a custom-defined Java class, you can use `ValueConverter` (from `jolie.runtime.JavaService`). For example, the `FileService` from the Jolie standard library uses it like this:

```
public static class StartsWithRequest implements ValueConverter
{
    private String self, prefix;

    private StartsWithRequest() {}

    public static StartsWithRequest fromValue( Value value )
    {
        StartsWithRequest ret = new StartsWithRequest();
        ret.self = value.strValue();
        ret.prefix = value.getFirstChild( "prefix" ).strValue();
        return ret;
    }

    public static Value toValue( StartsWithRequest p )
    {
        Value ret = Value.create();
        ret.setValue( p.self );
        ret.getFirstChild( "prefix" ).setValue( p.prefix );
        return ret;
    }
}

public Boolean startsWith( StartsWithRequest request )
{
    return request.self.startsWith( request.prefix );
}
```

Be wary that `ValueConverter` is still work in progress and there is no guarantee that the API will be kept stable in future versions of Jolie, we are still working on refining it (although it should not change or at least not change much).